# how to show Alert with TbAlert yii when delete data

Tags: yii, alert

i want to display the error with tbalert in admin page, the alert show when data is duplicate when user click delete in gridview, to check duplicate i used function beforedelete in model, but why does the alert  not show in admin page ?

```
 //code in model
    public function beforeDelete()
    {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->condition = 'idnasabah=:idnasabah';
        $criteria->params = array(':idnasabah'=>$this->idnasabah);
        if (Tbpinjaman::model()->exists($criteria)) {

            Yii::app()->user->setFlash(
                    'error',
                    '<strong>Ooops..!</strong> Data tidak dapat dihapus karena relasi dengan tabel pinjaman.'
                );
            return false;
        } 
        else {
           return parent::beforeDelete();
       }
    }

    //code in admin page
    <?php
    /* @var $this TbnasabahController */
    /* @var $model Tbnasabah */
    $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbAlert', array(
        'block' => true,
        'fade' => true,
        'closeText' => '&times;', // false equals no close link
        'events' => array(),
        'htmlOptions' => array(),
        'userComponentId' => 'user',
        'alerts' => array( // configurations per alert type
            // success, info, warning, error or danger
            'success' => array('closeText' => '&times;'),
            'info', // you don't need to specify full config
            'warning' => array('block' => false, 'closeText' => false),
            'error' => array('block' => false)
        ),
    ));

    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
                /*'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',*/
        'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'table table-striped table-bordered  table-condensed'),
        'id'=>'tbregister-grid',
         'filter' => $model,
        'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
        'template'=>'{items}{pager}',
        'columns'=>array(
            array(
                'header'=>'',
                 'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center;color:blue'),
                 'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center'),
                'value'=>'$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->currentPage*$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize + $row+1',
            ),
```

Comment: Did you use a redirect() after delete ?

Comment: didn't yet , i just return false

Comment: I think you should have a redirect() or render() method in your action for displaying the flash message.

Comment: i have try render and redirect but still not show the message like as i want

Comment: its solved with just simple solution , put $this->refresh(); in the last row of syntax actionDelete, thanks for u response